# Is it risky to include .env files in the .zip which is uploaded to Elastic Beanstalk for deployment? If so, what is the risk?

Tags: aws, client, secret-sharing, amazon, environment-variables

Is it okay to upload .env files containing client ID and client secret to elastic beanstalk? If not, what is the risk involved? How would one access those files?